# How to point allocWithZone: to a subclass under ARC (NOT a singleton!)

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass, objective-c-category

I've seen a few SO questions similar to this one, but they all involve singletons, and the answers are all (correctly) "don't do that, use dispatch_once() instead."

In my particular instance, I'm not making a singleton, and I need for the superclass's `allocWithZone:` to return an instance of my subclass.

What I'm trying to do is: I want to make an extension to an existing library that I don't own.  Rather than doing a bunch of behaviours in categories -- which won't even work properly if I'm overriding existing behaviour, because which-of-many same-signature methods gets called isn't defined -- I want it to be that, when someone includes my (very small) category, then calls

```
LibObject *myObj = [[LibObject alloc] init];
```

They get back, instead, as if they'd called

```
LibObject *myObj = [[MyLibObjSubclass alloc] init];
```

where `LibrarySubclass` is the subclass which I'm creating.  In particular, All of the library's objects that are subclasses of `LibObject`, I want them, instead, to be subclasses of `MyLibObjSubclass`.

I've messed with swizzling and categories and everything else I can think of, but I always end up with one of 2 problems: either

- I end up crashing after an infinite recursion of `[MyLibObjSubclass alloc]` calling `[LibObject alloc]` calling `[MyLibObjSubclass alloc]`, etc., or
- Everything that is a subclass of `LibObject`, rather than being a subclass of `MyLibObjSubclass`, with its new behaviours, it just *is* a `MyLibObjSubclass`, without any of the additional behaviours.

For this 2nd problem, by way of example, let's say I was trying to override all `UIView`-s to be `MyView`-s, where `MyView` is a subclass of `UIView`.  The problem is that, when I try to category-in (as part of `UIView+MyShim`), then this line:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

instead of returning a `UILabel` that is a subclass of MyView -> UIView -> UIResponder -> NSObject, it just returns a `MyView` which, for example, doesn't contain a `text` property, so all `UILabel`-s are broken.

So my question is: how do I do what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't stick your own class in the middle of an existing class hierarchy at runtime (because `class_setSuperclass` is deprecated).  Why can't you just swizzle each of the LibObject methods you need to override, and add new ones as necessary with `class_addMethod`?

Comment: Your question seems like “How do I use this screwdriver to put in these nails?” when it should be “How do I join these boards?”  Tell us why you think you need to add dozens/hundreds of methods to this mysterious unnamed library.

Comment: Screwdriver -> nails -- heh, yeah, this *might* be a case of that.  I wasn't trying to be secretive so much as wanting to abstract the question away from my specifics.  Specifically, I'm trying to create a library that goes on top of Cocos2d that allows me to override the `touchesBegan:` (and friends) behaviour of every `CCResponder` and also the `CCResponderManager`, while still allowing me to call the original methods.  Yeah, I could swizzle that in but, once I started experimenting, it became such a convoluted mess that I thought subclassing might be prettier.

Comment: ...So maybe my follow-on question should be: or is this just a case of "suck it up, cupcake" and I have to deal with the weird convolutions that get me to my desired touches behaviours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to modify the class hierarchy from this:

```
CCResponder
 └─ CCNode
     ├─ CCControl
     └─ CCSprite
```

to this:

```
CCResponder
 └─ MyResponder
     └─ CCNode
         ├─ CCControl
         └─ CCSprite
```

Since `class_setSuperclass` is deprecated, there's no supported way to make that change at runtime.

(**NOTE:** Yes, that's exactly what I was hoping to do.  ~Olie.)

Have you considered just modifying the Cocos2D source code?  Short-term, this should be the simplest approach.  If what you need is general enough, maybe you can get your changes merged upstream.  Or maybe you can add hooks that will be accepted upstream, and use those hooks to do what you need.

If you're keeping your code in git, then I recommend using the git-subtree extension to import the Cocos2D source code into your project's repository.  This makes it pretty easy to keep track of your local changes to Cocos2D and reapply them when you want to import a newer version.

If that doesn't work for you, I think you should just suck it up and use swizzling on the methods whose behaviors you want to change.

If you are a glutton for punishment, you can create a new subclass of each `CCResponder` subclass, on demand at runtime.  You'll end up with a hierarchy like this:

```
CCResponder
 └─ CCNode
     ├─ CCControl
     │   └─ hacked_CCControl
     └─ CCSprite
         └─ hacked_CCSprite
```

(I'm aware that `CCControl` isn't something you're likely to instantiate directly but let's pretend.)

I think this is possible, but pretty complicated.  To do it, swizzle `+[CCResponder alloc]` with (your own) `+[CCResponder allocHack]`.  You would implement something like this:

```
static Class createHackedClassForClass(Class originalClass) {
    NSString *name = [@"hacked_" stringByAppendingString:NSStringFromClass(originalClass)];
    Class hackedClass = objc_allocateClassPair(originalClass, name.UTF8String, 0);

    // Here add methods as necessary to hackedClass using class_addMethod.

    objc_registerClassPair(hackedClass);
    return hackedClass;
}

+ (void)allocHack {
    static NSMutableDictionary *hackedClassForClass = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    Class hackedClass = hackedClassForClass[self];
    if (hackedClass == nil) {
        hackedClass = createHackedClassForClass(self);
        hackedClassForClass[self] = hackedClass;
    }
    return class_createInstance(hackedClass, 0);
}
```

I haven't tried this so I don't know if there's any major problems with it.  It will at a minimum make things harder to debug than just modifying the Cocos2D source code.

Comment: Yeah, our shop was avoiding the "modify Cocos2d sources" solution because we didn't want to incur the "every time Cocos2d updates, we have to, too" cost.  We *may* still fall back to that, if I can manage to abstract things enough to make the changes small but, in the mean time, looks like I'm going to be sucking it up, as they say.  Thanks!

Comment: P.S.  I'm going to hold off a bit on accepting this answer because I still believe that the abstract question has merit.  Pre-ARC, all of this was possible (almost simple!), it's just that ARC doesn't allow `NSAllocateObject()` which, sans-ARC, would have solved all my problems (I think! ;) )  I suppose I could build an experimental project where I `-f-objc-no-arc` a test file and see if that actually works.  Man, what a hack!

Comment: If you use `NSAllocateObject` (or `class_createInstance` or `objc_constructInstance`), you'll get an object whose `isa` points to your class, not to the subclass you want (e.g. it points to `MyView`, not `UILabel`).  You want to get `MyView` into `UILabel`'s inheritance chain, but (since `class_setSuperclass` is deprecated) there's no supported way to do that.

Comment: Ok, yeah -- wow.  Great answer.  Uh... and so great that maybe you talked me out of the hack-y way.  But I still sort of have to try it, just so I can report back that I did my due diligence and decided on something else.  Ok, thanks a ton; you've been very helpful!  :)